# OkHttpClient with certificate return empty body, when I try with Postman I get a response?

Tags: android, ssl-certificate, okhttp

Here I create a OkHttpClient with client certificate and private key, seems that everything is ok but please if someone can check this.

```
private OkHttpClient setUpClient() {
    try {
        final String SECRET = "secret"; // You may also store this String somewhere more secure.
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        // Get private key
        InputStream privateKeyInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key);
        byte[] privateKeyByteArray = new byte[privateKeyInputStream.available()];
        privateKeyInputStream.read(privateKeyByteArray);

        String privateKeyContent = new String(privateKeyByteArray, Charset.defaultCharset())
                .replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                .replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), "")
                .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        ;
        byte[] rawPrivateKeyByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(rawPrivateKeyByteArray);


        // Get certificate
        InputStream certificateInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.certificate);
        Certificate certificate = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certificateInputStream);

        // Set up KeyStore

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(null, SECRET.toCharArray());
        keyStore.setKeyEntry("client", keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec), SECRET.toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{certificate});
        certificateInputStream.close();

        // Set up Trust Managers
        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
        if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:" + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
        }

        X509TrustManager trustManager = (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        // Set up Key Managers
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, SECRET.toCharArray());
        KeyManager[] keyManagers = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

        // Obtain SSL Socket Factory
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        //sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, new TrustManager[] { trustManager }, new SecureRandom());
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        // Finally, return the client, which will then be used to make HTTP calls.
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, trustManager)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        return client;

    } catch (CertificateException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException | KeyManagementException | UnrecoverableKeyException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here I create a OkHttp request,I create a formbody with params, request, and then I send request,code is 200, but body is empty. Is maybe something wrong with this call ?

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("action", "login")
            .add("username", etUsername.getText().toString())
            .add("password", etPassword.getText().toString())
            .add("pushid", sharedpreferences.getString(TokenVal, "")).build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(Common.prodURL)
            .post(formBody)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
            //.addHeader("Accept","multipart/form-data")
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {
            try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful())
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);


                System.out.println(responseBody.string());
            }
        }
    });
}
```